# How can you match all but the last word of a line?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I want to get two strings.  The last word on the line (which works below) and then everything BUT the last word, and I want to do this with regex.  Someone suggested I use **^(.*?)\b\w+$** as pattern and to use **$1** as a match (but I have no idea how to accomplish in .NET)

```
    Dim s As String = "   Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country    "
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "^[ \s]+|[ \s]+$", "")  'Trim whitespace
    Dim lastword As String = Regex.Match(s, "\w*$", RegexOptions.None).ToString
    Debug.Print(lastword)

    Dim therest As String = Regex.Match(s,......)
```

Comment: So remove the last word and pattern match against what's left

Comment: Why are you trimming like that? Try  "^\s+|\s+$".  And .NET Trim() would be even simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern should work, and what you're looking for is the first capture of the match collection:

```
Dim pattern As String = "^(.*?)\b\w+$"

' Use TrimEnd instead of regex replace (i.e. we don't nuke ant piles)
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input.TrimEnd(), pattern)

If match.Success Then
    ' It will be the 0th capture on the 1st group
    Dim allButTheLast As String = match.Groups(1).Captures(0)
    ' Group 0 is the entire input which matched
End If
```

Comment: works nicely.  But could you elaborate on why I'd want to use TrimEnd instead?

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit: regular expressions are like running another application inside you code. Intrinsic methods on `String` are stupid simple. Any time you choose to use a regex you should ask yourself "why?" They're great when they're appropriate and horrible when they're not.

Answer (score 4):

I know you wrote that you "want to do this with regex", but since a solution without regex is *so much easier*, *so much more readable* and *so less likely to contain hidden bugs*, I'll dare suggest it anyway:

```
Dim s As String = "   Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country    "
s = Trim(s)
Dim lastword = s.Split().Last()
Dim therest = Left(s, Len(s) - Len(lastword))
```

Alternatives:

```
Dim therest = Left(s, s.LastIndexOf(" "))
Dim therest = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(" "))   ' Thanks to sixlettervariables
Dim therest = String.Join(" ", s.Split().Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse())   ' for LINQ fanatics ;-)
```

Comment: How about, once trimmed, `input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf(' '))` for `lastWord`?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Thanks, nice alternative!